# How "this" keyword is using and working in Scala Auxiliary Constructor?

Tags: scala

I have started learning Scala just now, help me to understand that how the age is printing where student class has two parameters

```
class Student(id: Int, name: String) {
  var age: Int = 0
  def showDetails() {
    println(id + " " + name + " " + age)
  }
  def this(id: Int, name: String, age: Int) {
    this(id, name)
    this.age = age
  }
}

object hi {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var s = new Student(101, "Sun", 20);
    s.showDetails()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> that how the age is printing where student class has two parameters

`Student` has two constructors. An auxilary constructor with two parameters:

```
class Student(id: Int, name: String)
```

But it also defines an additional constructor with *three* parameters via `this()`:

```
def this(id: Int, name: String, age: Int)
```

When you create an instance of `Student` in `main`, you use the secondary constructor which accepts three arguments:

```
var s = new Student(101, "Sun", 20);
```

Thus, `20` is the age. If you'd use the auxiliary constructor, `age` would still be set to `0` making `showDetails()` print out `0`.

Answer (score 2):

When you construct this class with two parameters, then the construction process will first call:

```
var age: Int = 0
```

setting the age to 0. so the age of the student would be 0 unless you specifically change it.

When you call with three arguments, this is exactly what you do, you construct setting age to 0 and then change it to the third argument.

P.S. you are defining the id and name implicitly to be a private val. It would be better to do it explicitly.

The reason for this is that if you do:

```
class A(a: Int) {
}
```

then a is not part of the object at all, a is just an argument for the constructor.

If However you use a in a method:

```
class A(a: Int) {
  def b: Int = a
}
```

Then scala needs to save it for later use (it must be available outside the construction when b is called). It will therefore transform it to a private val.

To avoid confusion, it would be better to do:

```
class A(private val a: Int) {
  def b: Int = a
}
```